# How to make my character appear from the same door he got in the scene every time the scene gets reloaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a player that have to can go in four different rooms from one room (like a house).

Is it possible to set the player's position in front of the door he is getting in so every time you go back to the scene with the four doors, he is standing in front of the door he came from (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Are you sure you are using that language?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a Don't Destroy On Load https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html for that so you can save the right position before the next scene gets loaded. After that you can just load the last saved position when the scene gets loaded.